# Rails iOS homescreen web app - can't delete records

Tags: javascript, ios, ruby-on-rails, ios6, iphone-standalone-web-app

I've got a web app which works perfectly in the browser - both on the desktop and mobile.
The problem comes when I try to pretty it up by adding:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

This works great too - up to the point I need to delete a record in the app.

I'm also using this great gist I found - https://gist.github.com/1042167 to stop the app switching into mobile safari:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(document,navigator,standalone) {
        // prevents links from apps from oppening in mobile safari
        // this javascript must be the first script in your <head>
        if ((standalone in navigator) && navigator[standalone]) {
            var curnode, location=document.location, stop=/^(a|html)$/i;
            document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                curnode=e.target;
                while (!(stop).test(curnode.nodeName)) {
                    curnode=curnode.parentNode;
                }
                // Conditions to do this only on links to your own app
                // if you want all links, use if('href' in curnode) instead.
                if(
                    'href' in curnode && // is a link
                    (chref=curnode.href).replace(location.href,'').indexOf('#') && // is not an anchor
                    (   !(/^[a-z\+\.\-]+:/i).test(chref) ||                       // either does not have a proper scheme (relative links)
                        chref.indexOf(location.protocol+'//'+location.host)===0 ) // or is in the same protocol and domain
                ) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    location.href = curnode.href;
                }
            },false);
        }
    })(document,window.navigator,'standalone');
</script>
```

I'm wondering if this could be altered so data-method="delete" will play nice? at the minute - when I click 'Delete' - the 'are you sure?' confirm box hangs for a second or two, before dumping me back on the same Show page, with no delete having occured...

Answer (score 0):

*So I'm going to assume from what you've written that you are using the (bundled) `jquery-ujs` to handle your delete links for you as that sounds like what you're doing from your mention of `data-method`*

The way the `ujs` handlers work for delete links is different to what you might expect. Here's the relevant bit of [the `jquery-ujs` source](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js):

```
// Handles  "data-method" on links such as:
// <a href="/users/5" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow" data-confirm="Are you sure?">Delete</a>
    handleMethod: function(link) {
      var href = rails.href(link),
        method = link.data('method'),
        target = link.attr('target'),
        csrf_token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
        csrf_param = $('meta[name=csrf-param]').attr('content'),
        form = $('<form method="post" action="' + href + '"></form>'),
        metadata_input = '<input name="_method" value="' + method + '" type="hidden" />';

      if (csrf_param !== undefined && csrf_token !== undefined) {
        metadata_input += '<input name="' + csrf_param + '" value="' + csrf_token + '" type="hidden" />';
      }

      if (target) { form.attr('target', target); }

      form.hide().append(metadata_input).appendTo('body');
      form.submit();
    },
```

So you can see that's what actually happening is a form is being dynamically created (with the required `csrf` data) and then submitted.

Your delegated `click` handler method from the gist you link to isn't going to work in this situation, as the rails js does a `return: false` on click on links with a `data-method` attribute that prevents your handler from ever firing.

The simplest thing to do is probably to roll your own (ajax based) delete handler based on the `ujs` code. For brevity I'm using the excellent [jQuery form plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) to handle the actual submission:

```
function handleDeleteLink(endpoint){
  var confirmed = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?"),
    csrf_token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
    csrf_param = $('meta[name=csrf-param]').attr('content'),
    form = $('<form method="post" action="' + endpoint + '"></form>'),
    metadata_input = '<input name="_method" value="delete" type="hidden" />',
    deleteOptions = {
      beforeSubmit: function(){
        //handle ajax start
      },
      success: function(el){
        //hand success
      },
      error: function(){

      }
    };
    if (csrf_param !== undefined && csrf_token !== undefined) {
      metadata_input += '<input name="' + csrf_param + '" value="' + csrf_token + '" type="hidden" />';
    }
    if (confirmed){
      form.hide()
          .append(metadata_input)
          .appendTo('body')
          .submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
          })
          .submit();
    }
}
```

In your view just replace your`data-method` with a class of say `delete-link` and bind via event delegation (or use a different data attr if you like):

$('body').on('click', '.delete-link', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  handleDeleteLink(e.target.href);
}

Comment: thanks for your detailed reply. I added the plugin, removed the data-method, added the class and click handler, then added your function. Wonder if I need to comment some conflicting stuff out? I can navigate the app, but deletes are now just lifeless... also I'm still wondering why on my existing code - I only get a problem when it becomes an iOS homescreened web app.

Comment: Does the form get created/submitted correctly when handleDeleteLink() is called? I abstracted that code above from an app so could be I made an error when generalising it out. Your web inspector ought to be able to tell you where things are breaking

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `location.href = curnode.href;` changes requests into `GET` requests, although I've had inconsistent behavior with `POST` and `PUT` requests. So when you have some routes such as:

```
GET     /photos             index
POST    /photos             create
GET     /photos/new         new
GET     /photos/:id/edit    edit
GET     /photos/:id         show
PUT     /photos/:id         update
DELETE  /photos/:id         destroy
```

The `update` and `destroy` routes end up rerouted to `show`. My hacky (hopefully temporary) solution is to just make custom routes for those requests that are being rerouted. So you would add:

```
match "update" => "Photos#update", :as => :update_photo
match "destroy" => "Photos#destroy", :as => :destroy_photo
```

I know, I know, this is not Rails convention, but it should work.